# vba open csv file messed date format

Tags: excel, vba, csv, date

i'm using vba from `foo.xlsm` file, to open `bar.csv` file then copy it to the `foo.xlsm` file. however, surprisingly, it turns out that it will mess up with the date format, sometimes recognize as `mm/dd/yyyy`, sometims `dd/mm/yyyy`.

The csv file has a row like this:

```
"USD/MYR","TRF:1234","20/04/2017","01/06/2017","11/09/2017","01/06/2017"
```

, so all the dates are in `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

If I open `bar.csv` file manually, the 4 dates are shown correctly, as

```
20/4/2017   1/6/2017    11/9/2017   1/6/2017
```

However, if from `foo.xlsm` using vba to open `bar.csv` file, it turns out to be

```
20/04/2017  6/1/2017    9/11/2017   6/1/2017
```

, and hence later copied to `foo.xlsm` wrong dates.

It seems excel is tring to interprete the dates as `mm/dd/yyyy` first, only if that doesn't work, it'll read it as `dd/mm/yyyy`.

The vba code is like this:

```
Sub import_via_excel(source_file As String, source_sheet As String, target_sheet As String)
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wbThis = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim dest_sheet As Worksheet
    Set dest_sheet = wbThis.Sheets(target_sheet)

    Dim src_book As Workbook
    Set src_book = Workbooks.Open(source_file, True, True) ' Open in "ReadOnly" mode
    Dim src_sheet As Worksheet
    Set src_sheet = src_book.Sheets(source_sheet)
    src_sheet.Activate
    last_col = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    last_row = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Dim row As Integer          ' row counter.
    Dim col As Integer          ' col counter.
    Dim src_data  As String
    For row = 1 To last_row
        For col = 1 To last_col
            src_data = src_sheet.Cells(row, col).Value
            dest_sheet.Cells(row, col).Value = src_data
        Next col
    Next row

    src_book.Close False ' close file without saving (FALSE)
    Set src_book = Nothing

    wbThis.Activate

ErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

What could went wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `Workbooks.Open` to open your CSV file, Excel will convert dates to US format, unless it is impossible (so it will try other formats).

You can try adding an argument `Local:=True` to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Since it seems you're right that Excel is trying to interpret the dates as mm/dd/yyyy first, only if that doesn't work, it'll read it as dd/mm/yyyy:

Use the `NumberFormat` property to force the proper format:

```
For row = 1 To last_row
    For col = 1 To last_col
        dest_sheet.Cells(row, col).Select
        ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
        src_data = src_sheet.Cells(row, col).Value
        dest_sheet.Cells(row, col).Value = src_data
    Next col
Next row
```

Try that and see if it helps, forcing the proper date format onto each destination cell first.

Comment: But I can't know in advance what the format is, in a general function...

Comment: Perhaps, but could you not supply the desired format as another parameter?  Do you not know the desired format for any given input file?

Comment: Are these right, if considered in dd-mm-yyyy format? "20/04/2017","01/06/2017","11/09/2017","01/06/2017"  If  so, then perhaps your original data source formats days-first.  If those aren't correct, and those are a mix of formats, perhaps the best thing is to somehow enforce a standard format in your input, so that you can force it to be the way you want it.